# Lottery visa my wife

Tags: visas, usa

My wife was born in Cameroon being the principle applicant. We win the lottery  visa. Nationalise  in Nigeria. Am a nigerian born I  nigeria. Both of us has nigeria passport. Can trump travel ban affect our visa?

Comment: Questions about immigration belong on [Expatriates.SE].  It's not clear to me when the addition of Nigeria to the travel ban list is to take effect.  You might want to read the [relevant document](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/02/05/2020-02422/improving-enhanced-vetting-capabilities-and-processes-for-detecting-attempted-entry-into-the-united).  It doesn't seem promising, however, unless your visa has already been issued.

Comment: @noreputationplz the US [diversity visa lottery](https://dvprogram.state.gov/), popularly known as the green card lottery.

Comment: It took effect on the 21st of February 2020. And our interview date is approaching according to bulletin. We were selected because my wife was born in Cameroon. But we nationalise in nigeria holding nigeria passports. Her passport place of birth says LImbe Cameroon. But I was born here in nigeria and all our documents are readily available  she have gotten police clearance cert from Cameroon and nigeria too. Birth certificate, primary to secondary level certs from Cameroon. University  level she did in nigeria. But all my documents reads Nigeria.

Comment: Please who knows if we will be given visa or refused? Thanks

Comment: You have to be quick, even though you were drawn there's limited numbers, just apply and see what happens.